# How to change the room used

Tags: java, data-structures

I've researched this and so far not found what I was looking for here on the site. I'm more or less trying my hand at a semi-basic text based adventure type game where the player chooses an option such as (l)ook, (w)ander, (s)leep, etc. I've created the class for Room, and have initialized it and all the rest, and descriptions and the like are set. Inside one of the options, you enter a cave, and I have not learned enough from others and my teacher to allow the description of the area you are in to change. The lines of code so far for this are as follows:

```
public void Gameloop(Room startRoom)
{
    String input;
    boolean notDead = false;

    Room currentRoom = startRoom;

    while(!notDead)
    {
        //Shows description of the room
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, currentRoom.getDescription() + " What do you do? \n(l)ook around\n(g)rab a stick\n(s)leep.");
```

that is for the start of the game where you are in a forest. The description shows properly and advancement through choices is all proper. The problem is with this area of code

```
    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You see trees and a cave. Do you want to go into the casve? \n(y)es \n(n)o");
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {

            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,currentRoom.getDescription() + " Do you want to set up a camp?\n(y)es\n(n)o");
```

The problem specifically is that I have not learnt how to implement room changes at all, otherwise, the game basis would be sound and do-able, options would be more well thought out and an item system would later be implemented. Basically, how do I change the "room" the person is in. Note, this game has no GUI and is literally based on you typing a letter for each action

Comment: `currentRoom = cave;`

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the Strategy pattern here. Ill give you some pseudo code to get you started :), note this doesnt compile.
The idea is that you make a IRoom interface. This will allow you to make as many different kind of rooms as you like. Each room can define the actions that are possible in this room, so you can add certain actions to a forest room for example. 
It also has a method that will make sure the room performs the action. This could result in a roomchange, thus it will return a new IRoom.

```
      public class Game {
          private IRoom currentRoom;

          public void Gameloop(IRoom startRoom){

          while(!notDead)
          {
            //Shows description of the room
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, currentRoom.getDescription() + " What  do you do? " + dissplayPossibleActionsToUser(startRoom.getPossibleActionsInRoom()));

            Action chosenAction = dericeActionFromImput(input);
            currentRoom = startRoom.performAction(chosenAction);


          }

        }

     }

        public interface IRoom{
           //Returns all the actions the current room provides
           List<Actions> getPossibleActionsInRoom();

           //Does the action
           IRoom performAction(Action action);
        }

        public enum Actions{
           LOOK, WANDER, SLEEP;
        }


           public class Forest implements IRoom{

                public List<Actions> getPossibleActionsInRoom(){
                   return new ArrayList(Actions.wander);
                }

               public IRoom performAction(Action action){
                    if(action == wander){
                      return new HouseRoom();
                    }
                }
            }
```